# How to assign values to defined interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

I have interface defined for the response that I am trying to build fo rend client I see the `data` has response from the backend so now i am trying to assign values to my interface object it's coming undefined. Not sure why it casue this issue?

main.ts

```
  private async specialtyAccountBalanceResponse(@Body()data: IAccountBalanceSdkResult): Promise<any> {
      const saveDetails = {} as ICacheRequest;
      const specialtyResponse = {} as IGetAccountBalanceResponse;

      if (!data.Details && data.Header.StatusCode !== "0000") {
          return data.Header;
      }
      specialtyResponse.details.lineOfBusiness = "SPec";
      specialtyResponse.details.balanceAccount = data.Details.balanceAccount;
      return specialtyResponse;
  }
```

interface.ts

```
export interface IGetAccountBalanceResponse {
    header: any;
    details: IGetAccountBalanceDetails;
}

export interface IGetAccountBalanceDetails {
    lineOfBusiness: string;
    balanceAccount: string;
    payment: IPaymentIndicator;
}

export interface IPaymentIndicator {
    recentPaymentIndicator: string;
    recentPaymentAmount: string;
    achAuthRequiredInd: string;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's coming undefined?" What is `undefined`? Where?

Comment: after assigning the values it should have all those properties that are mapped but its printing `specialtyResponse` undefined

Comment: i don't get your question but generally `values cannot be assigned to interfaces in typescript`

Comment: @messerbill ok what would be correct approach if i have interface for response and build object

Answer (score 0):

You would rather define a class than an interface:

```
export class IGetAccountBalanceResponse {

    constructor(props?) {
       this.header = props.header;
       this.details = props.details;
    }

    public header: any;
    public details: IGetAccountBalanceDetails; 
}
```

you can then instantiate it like this:

```
const balance = new IGetAccountBalanceResponse()
```

or

```
const balance = new IGetAccountBalanceResponse(data)
```

This also works but should not be done unless there is a very good reason

```
const balance: IGetAccountBalanceResponse = {} as any;
```

Interfaces should not be used to instantiate objects but rather to define their type.

If you use a linter such as `eslint` (and I highly recommend that) you would see the error pop up before compiling.

Here you can try out: 
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

[Here are the official docs on it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xhq6sp)

Comment: `main.ts(82,15): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IGetAccountBalanceResponse'.
  Property 'header' is missing in type '{}'.` tried your approach getting this error

Comment: @hussain Okay so the last point was not right, I updated the answer. However you should always do `const x = new Foo()` for creating objects of a certain type.

Comment: `const specialtyResponse = new IGetAccountBalanceResponse(data)` header and details are getting undefined object

Comment: did you use a class?

Comment: @hussain I added a working example in stackblitz, check it out

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you create an empty object:

```
const specialtyResponse = {} as IGetAccountBalanceResponse;
```

Then you try to access a property of it:

```
specialtyResponse.details.lineOfBusiness = "SPec";
```

`details` is never instantiated, so it's `undefined`. Therefore you can't access it's property `lineOfBusiness`.

One solution would be to use classes like suggested by @undefinedMayNotBeNull. Another would be to just set `specialtyResponse.details` before accessing the properties.

```
specialtyResponse.details = {} as IGetAccountBalanceDetails;
```

Here's a working example:

```
interface IGetAccountBalanceResponse {
    details: IGetAccountBalanceDetails;
}

interface IGetAccountBalanceDetails {
    lineOfBusiness: string;
    balanceAccount: string;
}

const specialtyResponse = {} as IGetAccountBalanceResponse;
specialtyResponse.details = {} as IGetAccountBalanceDetails;

specialtyResponse.details.lineOfBusiness = "SPec";
specialtyResponse.details.balanceAccount = "Test";
```

[Try it on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IGetAccountBalanceResponse%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20details%3A%20IGetAccountBalanceDetails%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IGetAccountBalanceDetails%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20lineOfBusiness%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20balanceAccount%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20specialtyResponse%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20IGetAccountBalanceResponse%3B%0D%0AspecialtyResponse.details%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20IGetAccountBalanceDetails%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AspecialtyResponse.details.lineOfBusiness%20%3D%20"SPec"%3B%0D%0AspecialtyResponse.details.balanceAccount%20%3D%20"Test"%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(specialtyResponse)%3B%0D%0A)

---

**Update**

`specialtyResponse` may be a typo. Do you mean `specialityResponse` instead?